# Procedure entry point RegCloseKey not found in dynamic link library kernel32.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, dll, windows-server-2008

I have a program written in VC++, and I am trying to install it on Windows server 2008.

Initially it gave errors about api-ms-win-core-xx-l1.dll files were missing. So, I copied over my Windows 7 dlls to the application folder. But, now it gives an error saying

"Procedure entry point RegCloseKey not found in dynamic link library kernel32.dll"

I installed the latest VC++ redistributables, but it still doesn't seem to work. Do I have to replace the kernel32.dll file itself?

Comment: I won't recommend replacing of kernel32.dll... I don't believe you could... But if you succeed I think your server will crash and burn in flames!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, when I compiled the program for Windows 2003 platform(using libraries meant for Windows 2003), and it worked fine on this machine.

I was trying to use Windows 7 libraries because it is similar to Windows server 2008.

Answer (score 2):

Please, do not copy system files from one machine to another. It will end in disaster. The api-ms-win-core* files are into such category.
The VC++ redistributables and your program files should be enough. If this still fails, then post the error that you get then.

Comment: Ok, I deleted all the api-ms-win* dlls from the application folder. I uninstalled the vc++ redistributables and ran only the vc_redistx86 that came with the msi.

I get the error saying "api-ms-win-errorhandling-l1-1-0.dll was not found. reinstalling the application may fix this"

Comment: And it doesn't exist in the system32 folder either.

Comment: Can you use the Dependency Walker (http://www.dependencywalker.com/) into your executable and post its dependency tree?

Comment: How do I post the dependency tree? as a screenshot?

Comment: If it fits, an screenshot is nice. If not, Dependency Walker has a "Save" options that exports its view of the program to a TXT file (and other formats).

Answer (score 0):

If your application is 32-bit you need to install 32-bit VC Redistribute, and same thing goes for 64-bit. Remember, the bit-ness of your application that matters, not the bitness of OS.